# copying image from one table row to another table using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am copying content from one table to another as follows;

```
var ntr='',//to store html for new table row
rows=[],//to collect new rows
$tbl=$("#table_rolecart tbody"),//original table
l=$("tr", $tbl).length;
var row;
for(int i=0;i=0;i<l;){
        row=$("tr:eq("+i+")", $tbl);
  ntr= '<tr><td>'
  +$("td:nth-child(2)",row).text()+'<input type=hidden name="access_id" value='+accessid+'></td><td>'    //add item name
  +$("td:nth-child(3)",row).text()+'</td><td>'  //add description
  //want to add the third column which is an image with img tag
  + '</td></tr>'
```

I am currently doing like + row.find("img.role-action") where I want to add the image column but the table shows the [Object] instead of the image. How do I copy the image to the new table?

content of original table is as follows

```
<table class="table sortable" id="table_rolecart">
    <tbody>
              <tr class="odd">
                  <td><a href="#"><img src="/gra/images/icons/fugue/cross-circle.png" class="move-row" alt="Remove"></a></td>
                  <td>agile_unix_role<input type="hidden" value="1101" name="role_id"></td>
                  <td>this agile unix role</td>
                  <td><img alt="add" src="/gra/images/icons/fugue/plus-circle.png" id="role_action" class="role_action"></td>
             </tr>
             <tr class="slider">
                  <td colspan="4"><div class="sliding">Business Justification:<input type="text" name="ar_businessjust"></div></td>
             </tr>
             <tr class="slider">
                  <td colspan="2"><div class="sliding">Start Date: <input type="text" id="ar_startdate" value=""></div></td> 
                  <td colspan="2"><div class="sliding">End Date: <input type="text" id="ar_enddate" value=""></div></td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="height:8px">
             </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I want all the rows with all columns except the last row combined into one single row in the target table into seperate columns. I have acheived this , only thing remaining is the image in the first row's 4th column which I need to copy as the last column into target table

Comment: can you show an example of the original table html and another example showing what you want it to look like?

Comment: I've updated my post to an appropriate solution, at first I misunderstood you but that will do the trick.

Comment: @pri_dev looks like your selector is incorrect for the orignal table. It appears as though it should be `#role_action` but what you have is looking for an `img` tag witht he class name `role-action`. As long as you correct the `img` tag selector, my solution will give you what you want. Did you see the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$("td:nth-child(2)",row).html()` instead of `$("td:nth-child(2)",row).text()`

Comment: found this the most easiest to implement for image copy.. but I cant use .html() for text fields as I dont want the textboxes in the target table..

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

I misunderstood...this is what you want:

```
var html = $('<div>').append($('img.role-action').clone()).remove().html();
```

The above will give you the HTML for the selected image element including the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but I am thinking as you use row.find("img.role-action") to get the img object, you can use the following to print the image:

```
'<img src="'+row.find("img.role-action").attr("src")+'" />'
```

You may need to add more attributes to the image tag, depending on what you want.

Comment: I tried it and not sure why but its giving me this error: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/gra/ar_request/undefined"  (ar_request is the controller name)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `.html()` to just extract exactly what is inside that cell?

Comment: I am doing this way because I need 3 rows from original table copied in one row in newtable so I also have this in ntr+='<td>'+$(brow).find("input#ar_businessjust").val()+ '</td>' where  brow=row.next("tr"); , found it easier this way..